# How to pass a parameter into SQL Query?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have an SQLQuery:

```
SELECT * FROM (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY @sortColumns ) AS 'RowNumber'         
FROM MyTable WHERE '@keyword' = '' OR (AppId = '@keyword')) 
atd WHERE (RowNumber between @startRecord and @endRecord);
```

There 4 parameters in the query:

- sortColumns
- keyword
- startRecord
- endRecord

I've used VB.NET language to open a connection and pass values into the query via 4 parameters using Command.Paremeters:

```
Dim sortColumns = "AppId ASC"
Dim keyword = "abc"
Dim startN As Integer = 1
Dim endN As Integer = 20

Dim ds As New DataSet()
Dim strDatabaseConnectionString As String = ConfigHelper.MainConnectionString
Using connection As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(strDatabaseConnectionString)
    Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(query, connection)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@sortColumns", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = sortColumns
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@keyword", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = keyword
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@startRecord", SqlDbType.Int).Value = startN
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@endRecord", SqlDbType.Int).Value = endN

        Dim adapter As New SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        adapter.Fill(ds)
    End Using
End Using
```

When the code run into line **"adapter.Fill(ds)"**, it generate an exception.

> Exception Message: An expression of non-boolean type specified in a
>   context where a condition is expected

**My Suspicion:**

- Whether the way I pass the parameters' values is not correct
- We cannot pass a parameter as a column name

**Issue:** I don't know what wrong with the code that I've used to pass the values into sqlquery. Could you give me a suggestion for this issue?

Comment: Is it procedure or what

Comment: It is just a select statement.

Comment: If we focus on the VB code above, it look like I'm trying to replace some places inside the query. But Command.Parameters does't do a good job in this context.

Comment: Catch the executed query with profiler to see how is it.

Answer (score 1):

Where you have '@keyword', that literally means the string "@keyword". Remove the single quotes if you want to use the @keyword parameter.

You cannot refer to a column name in a parameter. This is a limitation of SQL Server, as it needs to compile your query before applying parameters.

Comment: You speak out of what my suspicion is. Somehow we cannot pass a column name there.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, your query will be:

```
SELECT 
* 
FROM (
        select 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY 'AppId ASC' ) AS 'RowNumber'         
        FROM 
            MyTable 
        WHERE 
            (''abc'' = '')
            OR (AppId = ''abc'') ) atd 
WHERE 
    (RowNumber between 1 and 20);
```

**EDIT**

After a short research I believe that Sql Server will try to execute this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT * FROM (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY @sortColumns ) AS ''RowNumber'' FROM MyTable WHERE ''@keyword'' = '' OR (AppId = ''@keyword'')) atd WHERE (RowNumber between @startRecord and @endRecord)',
N'@sortColumns nvarchar(9),@keyword nvarchar(3),@startRecord int,@endRecord int',@sortColumns=N'AppId ASC',@keyword=N'abc',@startRecord=1,@endRecord=20
```

For a query of mine like

`select @column from Table where @column = 1`

Sql Server executed:

`exec sp_executesql N'select @column from Table where @column = 1',N'@column nvarchar(10)',@column=N'contractId'`

and produce the error:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'contractId' to data type int.

So you can't pass a column because Sql Server will treat it like string.

I think the ;only solution for this is to construct completely your query from code and execute it.

Something like:

```
Dim sortColumns = "AppId ASC"
Dim keyword = "abc"
Dim startN As Integer = 1
Dim endN As Integer = 20

Dim sql As String = string.format("SELECT * FROM (select ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY {0} ) AS 'RowNumber'         
FROM MyTable WHERE @keyword = '' OR (AppId = @keyword)) 
atd WHERE (RowNumber between @startRecord and @endRecord);", sortColumns)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the query,

```
'@keyword' = ''
```

is not right.
Make your query in VB, replacing @keyword in code, not in the sql, so the generated sql is

columnname = ''

Comment: Even after I remove the single mark, it still generate the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in thinking that you cannot pass a column name as a parameter.

You could create the query in VB instead - if you are using VS2015 then your code could look like

```
Dim sortColumns = "AppId ASC"
Dim query = $"SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY {sortColumns}) AS 'RowNumber'
                             FROM MyTable WHERE @keyword = '' OR AppId = @keyword) AS atd
                             WHERE (RowNumber BETWEEN @startRecord AND @endRecord);"
```

- you shouldn't put quotes around the parameters,
- the `$` is for an [interpolated string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn961160%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) (new with VS2015).

For adding parameters, personally I prefer the style:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@keyword", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar, .Size = 50, .Value = keyword})
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@startRecord", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, .Value = startN})
cmd.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "@endRecord", .SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Int, .Value = endN})
```

(Change the value of the `.Size` parameter to match the size of the `AppId` column in the DB.)

I created a table in SQL Server and tested all the above and it worked.

Comment: Instead of passing sort column into the query using Command.Parameters, I can use other way to pass into the query using String.Format

Comment: There is no "AND" after atd. The query is just an outer select the inner select.

Comment: @Trind07 Oops! I was confused by the parentheses. Corrected.

Comment: @Trind07 It is better to use SQL parameters for the values rather than concatenating them in a string, but you have to put the column name in with concatentation.

Comment: I also have tried that. There is still an exception around this vb code. Could you please give me an example of how to pass parameter into select query?

Comment: @Trind07 I've added how I prefer to add SQL parameters and tested it as working.